# Where clause with sum aggregate in sql query

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions, mysql-workbench

I have a table and I want to display only those departments that have at least one registered user in them. My query is below:

```
SELECT departments.id as DepartmentID, 
       departments.depName as DepartmentName,
       SUM(IF(users.isDelete=0, 1, 0)) AS NumberOfUsers
FROM (myDB.departments) 
LEFT JOIN myDB.users ON departmentID=departments.id
AND `departments`.`isDelete` =  0
HAVING SUM(NumberOfUsers) >=0
```

The `HAVING SUM(NumberOfUsers) >=0` is not working at all. I would like to check if the `NumberOfUsers` is more than one then display it if not more than one then do not display it. Any suggestions?

Comment: More than one is `HAVING SUM(NumberOfUsers) >=1`

Comment: Dear, is Sql Server or My Sql?

Comment: Your having is working perfectly, as opposed to not at all. You just wrote it wrong. You want >0 and not >=0. Also, the numbe rof users is already summed up, so just use HAVING NumberOfUsers>0. Also grouping.

can also do an inner join and use where users.numberofusers>0.

Comment: why sum is there?? i think you need count of users??

Comment: In this case you need to use `GROUP BY` clause too:

Comment: Having `NumberOfUsers > 0 `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you need to use the `group by` clause too.

```
 SELECT departments.id as DepartmentID, 
        departments.depName as DepartmentName,
        SUM(IF(users.isDelete=0, 1, 0)) AS NumberOfUsers
 FROM (myDB.departments) 
 LEFT JOIN myDB.users ON departmentID=departments.id
     AND `departments`.`isDelete` =  0
 GROUP BY departments.id, departments.depName
 HAVING SUM(IF(users.isDelete=0, 1, 0)) >=0
```

But if you want a shorter answer, you can use `JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` and removing `HAVING` clause:

```
 SELECT departments.id as DepartmentID, 
        departments.depName as DepartmentName,
        SUM(IF(users.isDelete=0, 1, 0)) AS NumberOfUsers
 FROM (myDB.departments) 
 JOIN myDB.users ON departmentID=departments.id
     AND `departments`.`isDelete` =  0
 GROUP BY departments.id, departments.depName
```

Comment: is sum is needed here?? can used count with where clause for isdelete??

Comment: @VishalJAIN That should do also, but I was trying to keep the original code as much as possible

Comment: hmm I noticed it only returned a one row. .

Comment: @QWERTY Which one? And do you have more than one row when you execute the query without group by?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT departments.id as DepartmentID, 
       departments.depName as DepartmentName,
       (SELECT COUNT(u.id)
       FROM users u
       WHERE u.departmentID = d.id) as NumberOfUsers
FROM departments d
WHERE d.isdelete = 0
AND EXISTS
  (SELECT 'user'
  FROM users u
  WHERE u.departmentID = d.id)
```

In this way, you don't use a SUM in main query (where you must use GROUP BY to show other scalar fields like departments.id and departments.depName. In My Sql is not mandatory GROUP BY)

EXISTS clause garantee the presence at least one user. If you want to show all department (indipendently number of users, remove EXISTS clause)

Comment: upvote for this. It seems complicated but I think it's interesting. .

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simplify your query as you are checking condition in user table that is_delete should be 0, so there is no need of left join you can just use normal join. After this you are removing all rows those does not have record by having clause, so you can simply put this condition in where clause as per below-

```
SELECT dpt.id AS DepartmentID, dpt.depName AS DepartmentName, 
COUNT(usr.id) AS NumberOfUsers
FROM myDB.departments AS dpt 
JOIN myDB.users AS usr ON usr.departmentID=dpt.id
WHERE dpt.`isDelete` =  0 AND usr.isDelete=0
```

Note: Assuming users table have primary key as id, if not then you can use any other column in count function.